# Correspondence articles, do you put them in the CV?

Tags: cv, correspondence

Some journals have correspondence articles that vary in size and format. More importantly, they can be peer-reviewed or not (even in the same journal, like Nature Genetics for instance).

Do you write these publications in the CV? If so, do you put them in a separate category or together with your regular academic publications?

Comment: I think the question as it stands is too broad (as you say, there are different kinds of Correspondence, and it would be easier to answer if you were a bit more detailed). To provide a vague answer, though, I would separate pieces that were peer reviewed from those that were not. I think anything peer reviewed should count as an academic publication and as always, you should never judge a CV without reading the papers; journal name is never a guarantee of good science, so anyone seriously reading your CV can then make their own judgements as to how to weigh the Correspondence you've written.

Comment: Could you please explain "correspondence articles" more? What are they exactly?

Comment: @Parsa, you can have a look at the guidelines of [Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/others.html#correspondence) or [Nature genetics](http://www.nature.com/ng/authors/article_types/index.html). Nature says "These items are 'letters to the Editor': short comments on topical issues of public and political interest, anecdotal material, or readers' reactions to informal material published in Nature (for example, Editorials, News, News Features, Books & Arts reviews and Comment pieces)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following assumes that you do not have to follow strict guidelines for your CV (in which case you would most probably have consulted them already).

You put stuff on a CV for a reason, usually to showcase your achievements or experience. When deciding what to put on a CV, this should be your main criterion, i.e., do you think that whoever reads your CV will be positively impressed reading this – in contrast to being annoyed by having to read about every tiny thing you ever published? Whether the article in question is sufficiently noteworthy, is something that only you and people who are familiar with your work (such as a supervisor) can decide.

It might help to ask yourself the following questions:

- Are you at a stage where you list every publication, talk and poster on your CV or are you only listing “selected publications“?
- Is the correspondence relevant and can you expect the reader to know or see this? Did you, e.g., find a serious flaw in a publication that was considered seminal until your correspondence? Has your correspondence been cited?
- Did your correspondce require a noteworthy effort and can you expect the reader to know or see this?
- Are you the main contributor to the correspondence?

Considering where to put this correspondence, I would try to avoid creating a new category for one item only, i.e., I would put it in some fitting category or choose the categories such that it fits in one of them. Either way, I would ensure that the correspondence cannot be mistaken for a regular publication. If your correspondence does not have a title like ”Reply to …“, which makes this obvious, you can, e.g., append “(correspondence)” to the entry.

<sup>Disclaimer: The above is based on thought only. I have no experience in putting correspondce on a CV.</sup>